# unable to open "file name.txt" in octave using fopen

Tags: octave

How can I use the fopen function in octave to open a file whose name is *file name.txt*. I am using octave installed in windows.

thanks

Comment: type: `help fopen` in octave

Comment: Some programs have problems opening files with spaces in their names. Maybe that is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `fopen` to open the file and get the file id, the `"r"` stands for read mode.

```
fid = fopen("name.txt", "r");
```

Then use fgets to retrieve the file line by line and add it to a string. `fgets` will return -1 once the file has been completely read.

```
file_string = "";
while((line = fgets(fid)) != -1)
  file_string = strcat(file_string, line);
end
```

Close the file once your done reading it.

```
fclose(fid);
```

There you have it, you should now have a variable `file_string` which contains the contents of your file as a string. Obviously these utilities are much more versatile than just what I described above, so I'd also encourage you to read the docs at :

https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Opening-and-Closing-Files.html#Opening-and-Closing-Files